# "Can't mass-assign protected attributes" error, even they exists in attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr, accessible

I have a table, created from a database migration:

```
class CreateTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
create_table :tickets, :primary_key => :tickets_id do |t|
  t.string :title, null: false
  t.text :body
  t.datetime :create_date
  t.integer :author_id
  t.integer :status, null: false, default: 0
end
end
```

A model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title, :body, :create_date, :author_id, :status
end
```

And when I try to create a record:

```
User.create(title: title,body: body,create_date: Time.zone.now, author_id: @author_id,status: 0)
```

I get this error:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title, body, create_date, author_id, status

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create `User` instead of creating `Ticket`.

Change your code to:

```
Ticket.create(title: title, body: body, create_date: Time.zone.now, author_id @author_id, status: 0)
```

Hope, that it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a User instance and not a ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you hate marking each and every attribute in the accessible-list, you would prefer adding this in your config/application.rb

> config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false